# Android Fragments: Prevent mutiple addToBackStack calls

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId())
    {
    case R.id.bAddYourNumber:
        FragmentTransaction trans = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        trans.replace(R.id.root_frame, new InsertPastNumbersFragment());
        trans.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);

        trans.addToBackStack(TAG);
        trans.commit();

        break;
```

}

When the button is pressed, the fragment is replaced and the previous one placed into back stack. 
The problem is if the button is pressed several times, the same fragment is placed into backstack multiple times which results in the phone back button having to be pressed x amount of times the button was pressed to go back to the previous fragment.

Is there a way to control this to only add to back stack once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give your transaction a tag:

`trans.replace(R.id.root_frame, new InsertPastNumbersFragment())`

becomes

`trans.replace(R.id.root_frame, new InsertPastNumbersFragment(), PAST_NUM_TAG)`

Then, before handling the transaction, check:

```
if (getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(PAST_NUM_TAG) == null) {
    // Fragment hasn't yet been added, do the transaction
} else {
    // Fragment has already been added
}
```

Alternatively, if you have a button that triggers this, it might make more sense to just disable the button after you add the fragment to prevent the user from being able to press it more than once.

Comment: Thanks, im not sure if its the AVD emulator but I put the first line in my above code as bAddYourNumber.setEnabled(false) and im still able to press it at least twice now instead of multiple times.